# Use Angular2 validators outside of FormControl

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm building a model driven form in Angular2 RC5. In this form I have an option where the user can add multiple users from a file or by hand by entering some information. The file will be parsed in JavaScript and the data will be displayed in a table. To validate the form I created a validator similar to the build in ones which I found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/src/validators.ts). Here's an example of my implementation:

```
import {AbstractControl, ValidatorFn} from "@angular/forms";

export class StringValidators {
    static isEmail(options: Object): ValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
            var val: string = control.value;
            // ... cut ...
            var regEx = new RegExp(`^${exp}$`);
            return regEx.test(val)?null:{"isEmail":true};
        };
    }
}
```

Then I can add the validator to `FormControl` like this:

```
 userEmail = new FormControl("", [StringValidators.isEmail]);
```

However this will only work for a text input field. I also have the scenario of adding multiple users from a file. I don't quite understand how the validator is called inside of the FormControl class. My only idea to make it reusable is to extract my validation logic to a separate class and then building a wrapper around it for Angular.

Is this the best way to accomplish this? Or am I over-complicating things?

Comment: Don't tag typescript and javascript together unless it has anything to do with transpiling!

Comment: Ok this makes sense, fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an intermediate type to wrap the logic :

```
export type ValidatorAndValueFn<T> = { validator: ValidatorFn, validate: ((value: T) => ValidationErrors | null) };

export class StringValidators {

//Private logic (could be a service or anything else)
  private static emailValidation = (value: string) => {
    const exp = "emailRegEx";
    const regEx = new RegExp(`^${exp}$`);
    return regEx.test(value) ? null : { "isEmail": true };
  }

  static isEmail(): ValidatorAndValueFn<string> {
    return {
      validator: (control: AbstractControl) => StringValidators.emailValidation(control.value),
      validate: (value: string) => StringValidators.emailValidation(value)
    }
  }
}

//in Form
    userEmail = new FormControl("", [StringValidators.isEmail().validator]);


//Out a Form
    StringValidators.isEmail().validate("test");
```